# Is the shower into 72000 nadis repeatable?

Tags: yoga, kundalini

Suppose a person has Kundalini activated and crossed all chakras and reached sahasrara. Then a shower will happen and flow through all 72000 nadis of the yogi.

Does the shower happen only at first time when kundalini reaches sahasrara or is it repeatable at any time later?

Comment: i dont think it means kundalini raising at all its normal when you sit and do mantra japa..

Comment: please check sivananda.org they have the meditation experience